# What should the tag for Visual Studio Lightswitch be?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Microsoft has just revealed “[Visual Studio Lightswitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/default.aspx)”, what tag should we use for it, I think it should be [visual-studio-lightswitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=visual-studio-lightswitch&sort=info&pagesize=30).

Answer (score 4):

Considering [visual-studio-lightswitch] is just at 25 characters and thus usable, it seems like a perfect tag - you'll get it in your autocomplete whether you start with "visual studio" or "lightswitch".

It might be wise to add a synonym coming from [lightswitch], provided we don't have anything else that could be tagged as such. [vs-lightswitch] might also be an option.

Comment: I have added some synonyms, please upvote them on the tag page if you like them. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=visual-studio-lightswitch&sort=info&pagesize=30

Comment: @Ian Ahahaha, I can't vote on those. Maybe I should start pushing for 2k on Stack Overflow at some point...

Comment: Not worth the effort.

Comment: @Lady Probably not. I'll just suffice to slowly trickle up over time.

Answer (score 0):

"What Grace Note said"

Edit: Grace Note: Arrgh.. you beat me... I shouldn't be doing other stuff in between answering questions :P

Comment: How did I beat you? We have opposing viewpoints so it isn't as if my earlier timestamp matters.

Comment: Well, by suggesting the two tags in your second paragraph... I do have to say I like your synonym idea even better