# Lightswitch should be a synonym for visual-studio-lightswitch (or vice versa)

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Currently both the tags [lightswitch](/questions/tagged/lightswitch) and [visual-studio-lightswitch](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-lightswitch) exist. None of them are synonoms.

Which one that should be the synonym has been discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59759/what-should-the-tag-for-visual-studio-lightswitch-be) before.

I prefer [lightswitch](/questions/tagged/lightswitch), but either is fine. However it should be one or the other.

Could a person please create the synonym (a person with high enough rep that is.).

---

**Update:**

the [lightswitch](/questions/tagged/lightswitch) and [visual-studio-lightswitch](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-lightswitch) tags are still untouched.

Comment: The synonyms [have been proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-lightswitch/synonyms), but they haven't received enough votes to take effect yet. I imagine that lots of people, like myself, don't have the trivial 5 score in such an obscure tag to vote for them.